# Backbone: Adding a model to a collection from a collection view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have some code where I want a NoteCollectionView to add a new Note to the NoteCollection. This is triggered by a function newNote in the NoteCollectionView:

```
newNote: function(data) {
    var note = new Note(data);
    this.collection.add(note);
},
```

I'm still very new to backbone, and I want to make sure this syncs with the server. The concerns I have are:

1) Will simply adding this note to the collection trigger a save() from the server, and update the model with the ID that the server gives it? Or,

2) If the server does not update my model and give me an actual ID, how do I save the model with note.save() and get back an ID from the server?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To address your first question, no, `.add` will not trigger any kind of call to the server; it will only add a model to a collection.

However, you do have a couple options. One would be to create the new note model, save it to the database, and then add it to the collection:

```
newNote: function(data) {
    var note = new Note(data);
    note.save();
    this.collection.add(note);
}
```

The second option is to simply use [Backbone's collection.create method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create). Give it a hash of attributes and it will

1. Create the model
2. Save it to the database
3. Add it to the collection

All in one fell swoop, like so:

```
newNote: function(data) {
    return this.collection.create(data);
}
```

`collection.create` also returns the newly created model, illustrated by my return statement above.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! So what parameters should my servlet take in, and should it write the new model to the returned JSON in the response?

Comment: `collection.create` uses `model.save`, so assuming your models are correctly saving to the database, no further changes are needed. In general, I tend to return the model's attributes as JSON after saving and setting them to the Backbone model; this gives me the flexibility to alter some attributes during the save operation, and the Backbone model's data will reflect these alterations after the save completes

Comment: create will work great - is there an option we can pass to prevent it from saving to db?

Comment: If your request fails (through .create) the model is still added to the collection.